# Confused on hierarchy in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If we can do this:

```
class Child
  def child_method
    puts "hi world"
  end
end

child = Child.new
child.child_method
```

Which calls the method puts which is defined in Kernel and mixed in Object.

Why can't we do this:

```
class Parent
  def test
    puts "hi from parent"
  end
end


class Child
  def child_method
    test
  end
end

child = Child.new
child.child_method
```

Why can't we call the method on a Parent object, as we do with "puts"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wirte as below :

```
class Child
  def child_method
    puts "hi world"
  end
end
```

By defaults `Object` becomes super class of `Child`. `Object` mixed in the Kernel. So `Kernel` also in the ancestor chain of `Child`. Thus you are able to call the `puts` private method of `Kernel`.

```
child = Child.new
child.class.ancestors # =>[Child, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Now coming to your below class definitions:

```
class Parent
  def test
    puts "hi from parent"
  end
end
p Parent.ancestors # => [Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

class Child
  def child_method
    test
  end
end
p Parent.ancestors # => [Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

As you didn't inherit `Parent` to `Child` class, again `Object` becomes the default super class of `Child`. So the `test` method will not be available to the `Child` class.If you want it do as below :

```
class Parent
  def test
    puts "hi from parent"
  end
end


class Child < Parent
  def child_method
    test
  end
end

child = Child.new
child.child_method # => "hi from parent"
```

Now it is working as the `Parent` is now in the ancestor chain of `Class`.

```
child.class.ancestors # => [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to inherit. `class Child < Parent` and it works. Just because you call the classes `Child` and `Parent`, they don't become so. :P

Comment: Oh dear. Yes I forgot.